# Error when opening application using GeckoFX

Tags: c#, geckofx

Just to test geckofx45 on visual studio 2013, I made a simple program with a geckofx control and put Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox"); under InitializeComponent();

and I get this error

"An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in Geckofx-Core.dll but was not handled in user code"

What is going on!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely a issue with a handled exception, stopping when debugging:

https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues/159/getting-systemnotimplementedexception

setting EnableProfileMonitoring should prevent the exception.

```
Xpcom.EnableProfileMonitoring = false;
Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
```

Comment: @JimmyX You should then upvote the answer and mark it as selected. +1 from me